# How to fill a DataGrid with items having a Dictionary as member and seperate it's keys in individual columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have an ObservableCollection of 'Project' objects, where 'Project' is:

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProgramManager { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, List<String>> MapRole { get; set; }
    public bool HasConsumer {get; set;}     //per indicare se sono presenti consumer tra gli approvatori
    public bool HasMoreUser { get; set; }   //per indicare se sono presenti più utenti nei ruoli approvatori
}
```

Is there a way to represent this ObservableCollection in a DataGrid? I mean, I'd like to show a column for every field present in my 'Project' class plus a column for every key in the MapRole dictionary. So for example:

Name | ProgramManager | Key1 | Key 2 | .... | Key N | Has Consumer | HasMoreUser

I haven't done so much since I have no idea how to implement that:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListProject}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Could someone help me, please? Or at least give me a well-explained tutorial how to customize a DataGrid following the MVVM pattern. Thanks!

Comment: custom datagrid or custom datagrid cell/column/row styles ? And if u want a custom control creating tutorial,wouldn't that be too broad to answer here ?

Comment: Let me explain a few things...The customization is entirely up to you.Write the xaml for your ui as you want...I think u should rather ask for databinding of the datagrid ?

Comment: FYI the title of a question should NOT be a list of tags - thats what the tagging system is for - adjust my title as you see fit (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190)

Comment: Yes, sure. That was my question for. Actually I'm unable to bind the datagrid columns to every properties (including the dictionary).